# Using a longPressAction within a List and NavigationLink

Tags: list, scrollview, gesture, swiftui

Unlike in `UIKit`, where a `LongPressGesture` is actually delayed, in `SwiftUI` it began as soon as you hover/pan/touch the view. So if you have a `LongPressGesture/Action` in a `View` within a `List` or a `NavigationLink`, it'll prevent scrolling the `List`, or triggering the `NavigationLink` action.

Anyone have any idea if it's possible to delay it with current API?

Comment: Same happens within a ScrollView. Did you find any solution?

Comment: The only way I've found to add a gesture to a `ScrollView` (or `List`) without blocking the scroll – is to add it directly to a `ScrollView` using `simultaneousGesture`.